# Authentication terminology

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc

Below comes a Value Object to represent `UserId` in ASP.NET application. It implements Value Identity, so equality is defined by matching of the state calculated at the moment of comparison. It depends on

```
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    int CurrentUserId { get; }      // may be impersonated     
    int InteractiveUserId { get; }  // "real" user, may impersonate
}
```

which extracts state from `ClaimIdentity`.

Here is a definition:

```
public struct UserId 
{
    public static IAuthenticator Authenticator { get; set; }

    public static readonly UserId Anonymous = 
        new UserId(() => 0);

    public static readonly UserId Current = 
        new UserId(() => Authenticator?.CurrentUserId ?? 0);

    public static readonly UserId Interactive = 
        new UserId(() => Authenticator?.InteractiveUserId ?? 0);

    public UserId(int value)
        : this(() => value)
    {
    }

    UserId(Func<int> getValue)
        : this()
    {
        GetValue = getValue;
    }

    public bool Authenticated => this == Current && this != Anonymous;
    public bool Impersonated => this == Current && Current != Interactive;
    public bool Impersonating => this == Interactive && Current != Interactive;

    Func<int> GetValue { get; }
    int Value => GetValue?.Invoke() ?? 0;

    public static implicit operator int(UserId id) => id.Value;

    public static bool operator ==(UserId left, UserId right) =>
        left.Value == right.Value;

    public static bool operator !=(UserId left, UserId right) =>
        left.Value != right.Value;

    // Equals, GetHashCode are omitted for brevity
}
```

We can do the following now:

```
   if(UserId.Current.Authenticated) ...
   if(UserId.Current.Impersonated) ...
   if(UserId.Interactive.Impersonating) ...
```

Also:

```
   var uid = new UserId(33);
   if(uid.Authenticated) ...
   if(uid.Impersonated) ...
   if(uid.Impersonating) ...
```

And provide overloads in extension methods:

```
   interface IAuthorizer
   {
      void Authorize<TResource, TAction>(int resourceId, UserId userId);
   } 

   static class AuthorizerExtensions
   {
      public static void Authorize<TResource, TAction>(
           this IAuthorizer authorizer, int resourceId) =>
           authorizer.Authorize<TResource, TAction>(resourceId, UserId.Current);              
   }
```

It is intended to be used [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124487/multitenant-app-authorization). GitHub [repository](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/Authorizers) (just a sketch).

Do these terms (`Anonymous`, `Current`, `Interactive`, `Authenticated`, `Impersonated`, `Impersonating`) properly used here and look understandable? Do they have an expected behavior?

Comment: I would use `IsAuthenticated` etc., [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3906677/648075). See also: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/30914/10582 Microsoft says: ["DO name Boolean properties with an affirmative phrase (CanSeek instead of CantSeek). Optionally, you can also prefix Boolean properties with 'Is,' 'Can,' or 'Has,' but only where it adds value."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx).

Comment: @BCdotWEB There is more in the [book](http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613): _"`Created` is more readable than `IsCreated`. Having the prefix is often too verbose, ... It is just as clear to type `MyObject.Enabled =` and have Intellisense ... as it is to have`MyObject.IsEnabled` =, and the second one is more verbose. ... Test out the API in an if-statement. `if(collection.Contains(item))` vs `if(collection.IsContained(item))`"_. Should I have `IsAuthenticated` but `Impersonated`? My English is far from perfect :(